# getcell().setCellValue() gives null pointer exception

Tags: java, excel, xssf

I am getting a cell from excel sheet and then I have to set its value.

```
XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
 XSSFCell resultCell=null;

 if(   sheet.getRow(1).getCell('A')==null)
{ sheet.getRow(1).getCell('A').setCellValue("heh");}
```

But this gives a null pointer exception.

Comment: So either `sheet` or `sheet.getRow(1)` is `null`.

Comment: @Tunaki it does get sheet in first statement. It raises this exception with in if block

Comment: Yes, because one of the two is `null`. If it isn't `sheet` then it is `sheet.getRow(1)`.

Comment: Why is it null (sheet.getRow())?